# Retrieving a video's play-time that is embedded in an R Shiny app

Tags: html, r, shiny, shinyjs

I am trying to embed a video in a Shiny app and have an action button that, when pressed, records the play-time of the video. For the purposes of this questions I really just want to paste/renderText the play-time on the screen. I am using the code below to get the video in and I have seen ways to accomplish this entirely in HTML but can't seem to get it to work in Shiny.

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(), 

  tags$video(src = "my_video.mp4", type = "viedo/mp4", width = "500px", height = "300px", controls = "controls"), 
  actionButton(inputId = "get_time", label = "Get Time"), 
  textOutput("currentTime")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way.

```
library(shiny)

js <- 
  "Shiny.setInputValue('time', document.getElementById('myVideo').currentTime);"

ui <- fluidPage(

  tags$video(id = "myVideo", src = "my_video.mp4", type = "video/mp4", 
             width = "500px", height = "300px", controls = "controls"), 
  actionButton(inputId = "get_time", label = "Get Time", onclick = js), 
  textOutput("currentTime")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output[["currentTime"]] <- renderText({
    input[["time"]]
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```